# Microsoft Hardware dashboard API: 503 Service Unavailable on committing a product submission

Tags: python, windows, driver, hardware

I am using the hardware API to automate the process of submitting package for signing drivers to Microsoft's Partner center Dev Portal:

https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard

The documentation link is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/dashboard-api

I am successfully able to create a new product,a new submission and upload the package azure blob storage. However when I try to commit the submission 
I get 503 Service Unavailable response. The commit worked only once so far and all the other times it gives 503 response code.

**Python** code for committing the submission is as follows:

```
http.client.HTTPSConnection("manage.devcenter.microsoft.com")
ingestionConnection.request("POST","/v1.0/my/hardware/products/{0}/submissions/{1}/commit".format(productID,submissionID),"", headers=headers)
commitIapResponse = ingestionConnection.getresponse()
print(commitIapResponse.status)
print(commitIapResponse.reason)
```

I expect the product to get committed so that the partner center account knows package is submitted for signing. 
The error on committing is response code 503 Service Unavailable. 
I don't understand the intermittent behavior. Please help!

Comment: The unsuccessful commit do create a new product and submission on partner center portal. However after clicking in the product the following error       
**Error**
The page you are trying to access isn�t available right now. Please try again soon.

Comment: Can you post a Fiddler trace of your session that shows the entire request and response headers?